# Failed to set up up DAX with DynamoDB in python

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I set up a DAX cluster which seems to work. I can connect to it with a telnet.

Here is my part of my script which works with DynamoDB

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
```

But it I only add there DAX endpoint

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', 
               endpoint_url='dax-test.awj2jy.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111'
                      )
```

script fails

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get.py", line 25, in <module>
    endpoint_url='dax-test.awj2jy.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111'
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 836, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 71, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 281, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 79, in get_client_args
    timeout=(new_config.connect_timeout, new_config.read_timeout))
  File "/home/ubuntu/dax/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 273, in create_endpoint
    raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url)
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: dax-test.awj2jy.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111`

Is there something more I should do?
I'm using boto3 v1.4.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DAX wire protocol is not compatible with HTTP-based DynamoDB protocol. DAX currently has an SDK for Java. SDKs for other languages are being actively developed. For more information about how to use the Java SDK for DAX, please refer to the [user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.html).

While you may use boto3 for provisioning your DAX cluster. You cannot connect to the cluster using Python just yet.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I wrongly assumed that all I need is to change the endpoint.

Comment: Python SDK for DAX was just [released](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-releases-sdks-for-python-and-dot-net-support-for-t2-instances-and-now-available-in-the-asia-pacific-singapore-and-asia-pacific-sydney-regions/), check it out

Comment: DAX is [API compatible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-adds-dynamodb-transactions-support-for-python-and-net/) with DynamoDB as of 2019